# jboss java random Full GC freezing app

Tags: java, jboss, garbage-collection, performance

Hi i'm working on java apps with 6 application server balanced and i got freezing full gc (causing timeout in app) random in 1 of they, around 1-2 application server for day.

GC.log

...

```
2011-12-13T10:38:36.576+0100: 79825.032: [GC [PSYoungGen: 874833K->66144K(1071936K)] 3516152K->2809316K(3868160K), 0.2535770 secs] [Times: user=0.94 sys=0.00, real=0.25 secs]
2011-12-13T10:38:36.830+0100: 79825.286: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 66144K->0K(1071936K)] [ParOldGen: 2743171K->2753089K(2796224K)] 2809316K->2753089K(3868160K) [PSPermGen: 283256K->269894K(524288K)], 7.3616280 secs] [Times: user=25.14 sys=0.00, real=7.36 secs]
2011-12-13T10:38:46.152+0100: 79834.608: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 752192K->0K(1071936K)] [ParOldGen: 2753089K->2751441K(2796224K)] 3505281K->2751441K(3868160K) [PSPermGen: 270340K->269781K(524288K)], 6.6231180 secs] [Times: user=22.52 sys=0.01, real=6.62 secs]
2011-12-13T10:38:54.591+0100: 79843.047: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 752192K->0K(1071936K)] [ParOldGen: 2751441K->2719651K(2796224K)] 3503633K->2719651K(3868160K) [PSPermGen: 270670K->269784K(524288K)], 5.5780510 secs] [Times: user=19.75 sys=0.01, real=5.58 secs]
```

...

My actually workaround it's kill jboss and restart it (not nice solution).

This is my system conf:

```
Mem: 6 Gb
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5640  @ 2.27GHz (4 core)
java version "1.6.0_26"
Scientific Linux release 6.0 (Carbon)
jboss-4.0.5.GA
```

Jboss parameters:

```
-Xms4G 
-Xmx4G 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:PermSize=512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC 
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 
-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy 
-XX:+AggressiveOpts 
-Xdebug
```

Anyone can help me pls?
Thanks

Comment: can you try with Java 7? it should work more smoothly with GC

Comment: I won't recommend to run this with Java 7, the Jboss version is too old... Mostly like Java 7 is unsupported, I'm even wondering whether java 6 is supported with jboss 4.0.5

Comment: I can't because it's a production.

Comment: @MarkBramnik makes sense, I didn't notice there is such an old version of JBoss.

Comment: Perhaps expanding permsize some. Also, I've found that 4.0.x versions of JBoss are kinda problematic when one needs to found a proper config for JVM instance (something also caused by old and big apps).

Comment: 4.0.5 should not be run with java 6. See here : http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossVsJavaJDKVersionMatrix

Comment: Also, since you are not running cms you can get rid of the CMSClassUnloadingEnabled flag.

Comment: Since you have specified the parallel gc a full gc will be a stop the world gc. You could try with cms instead (as stated below).

Comment: You might actually be running with too large heap. It takes time to do a full gc on a large heap. With a smaller heap you might get more full gc:s but they are faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using adaptive sizing policy: -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy and -XX:MaxGCPauseMilis=100 and -XX:GCTimeRatio=19?

If that doesn't help then Concurrent Mark Sweep Collector (-XX:UseConcMarkSweepGC)?

If you have time have a look at the presentation titled "Everything I Ever Learned About JVM Performance Tuning @Twitter" ([slides](http://www.slideshare.net/aszegedi/everything-i-ever-learned-about-jvm-performance-tuning-twitter), [video](http://www.parleys.com/#id=2662&st=5)), it explains the tradeoffs when it comes to picking a GC.

Comment: If you do this you have to change the -Xms so that it is not equivalent to -Xmx. That disables the ergonomics of the vm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go into profiling your application here, I'm afraid there is no other choice...
Does full-GC freeze without the cluster? 
You can try to run with different GarbageCollector, but probably the cause of such a behavior is a memory leak somewhere in your application, or at least "suspiciously wrong" object treatment in terms of memory consumption.

Another thing you can do is to generate heap dumps over the day and see whether there is any difference that can point to the problem.

BTW, I suppose its 64 bit java and jboss, right? :) For 32 bit application is a little bit problematic to handle 4 GB memory in the same process...

Comment: A full gc always stops the application at some point, the question is how long the app is stopped.